# Batocera to bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu and windows on same disk. My system also have a secondary drive (M.2) with batocera on it.
I want to add the batocera line into the grub to have the ability to start from linux bootloader same as I have now with Kubuntu and Windows.
I suscessfuly mounted batocera drive, I know the UUDI, I added to the FSTAB, but I can't see it on my grub list when I iniciate my system. I only see the same OS: Kubuntu and Windows.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu question and answer site.Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  So you may be better supported in other sites like https://unix.stackexchange.com/  Did you create an ESP - efi system partiiton as FAT32 and extract batocera's boot files into it like it says? Then `sudo update-grub` should add it to grub's menu. If not post details & issues in other sites.